# FIrebug 1.5 not installing properly on Firefox 3.6

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, installation, firebug

I just installed Firefox 3.6 (updated it, rather) and when I tried to install Firebug (1.5) it says 'addon installed' but there's no sign of Firebug anywhere. F12 doesn't do anything, the 'bug' icon in the bottom right isn't there, and nothing's in the Extra menu as well! Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Another plugin was causing firebug not to start properly. In my case this was the Microsoft .NET Framework Assistant. Disabling this plugin solved the error.

Comment: If you can reproduce the behaviour it would be a good idea to raise it as a bug with the Firebug team. While it may no be their "fault" (it could be an unintended  interaction between their code, the MS code, and possibly some other extension(s) you have installed) they'll probably want to know so they can look into it and either fix the problem (if it is their code), work around it (if it can otherwise be reliably reproduced and diagnosed), or just let people know to expect the issue in some instances and how to resolve it if they do.

Comment: Sure I can reproduce it: just enabling the .NET Framework Assistant will break Firebug again. 
Older versions of Firebug (pre 1.4) works on Firefox 3.5 with .Net Framework Assistant on, but since you need firebug 1.5+ for Firefox 3.6 I couldn't stick to the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a fresh profile on your Firefox install?

```
Start -> Run -> "firefox.exe -profilemanager".
```

Start a 2nd profile (probably will have to make a new one), and install firebug on there. If it works OK, you have an issue with your current profile. If not, there is any issue with the general firefox install.

Comment: Yes I have, I deleted the default profile and created a new one. Installed Firebug on this profile, same problem. Will try reinstall firefox alltogether (brb ;))

Comment: ...aaand to no avail.

Comment: So you have tried a new profile, no dice. Uninstalled Firefox, re-installed firefox, still no dice?